Grafana dashboard provisioning on a Docker container
I've been trying to provision a dashboard on a Docker hosted Grafana server. My repository is set up as follows:
Docker

/dashboards
dashboard.JSON
dashboard.yaml
datasource.yaml
(some other files irrelevant to this discussion)

dashboard.JSON
{
"annotations": {
"list": \[
{
"builtIn": 1,
"datasource": {
"type": "grafana",
"uid": "postgres"
},
"enable": true,
"hide": true,
"iconColor": "rgba(0, 211, 255, 1)",
"name": "Annotations & Alerts",
"type": "dashboard"
}
\]
},
"editable": true,
"fiscalYearStartMonth": 0,
"graphTooltip": 0,
"id": 1,
"links": \[\],
"panels": \[
{
"datasource": {
"type": "grafana-postgresql-datasource",
"uid": "postgres"
},
"fieldConfig": {
"defaults": {
"color": {
"mode": "thresholds"
},
"custom": {
"align": "auto",
"cellOptions": {
"type": "auto"
},
"inspect": false
},
"mappings": \[\],
"thresholds": {
"mode": "absolute",
"steps": \[
{
"color": "green",
"value": null
},
{
"color": "red",
"value": 80
}
\]
}
},
"overrides": \[\]
},
"gridPos": {
"h": 8,
"w": 12,
"x": 0,
"y": 0
},
"id": 1,
"options": {
"cellHeight": "sm",
"footer": {
"countRows": false,
"fields": "",
"reducer": \[
"sum"
\],
"show": false
},
"showHeader": true
},
"pluginVersion": "10.4.2",
"targets": \[
{
"datasource": {
"type": "grafana-postgresql-datasource",
"uid": "postgres"
},
"editorMode": "code",
"format": "table",
"rawQuery": true,
"rawSql": "select \* from retrievescripts()",
"refId": "A",
"sql": {
"columns": \[
{
"parameters": \[\],
"type": "function"
}
\],
"groupBy": \[
{
"property": {
"type": "string"
},
"type": "groupBy"
}
\],
"limit": 50
}
}
\],
"title": "Panel Title",
"type": "table"
}
\],
"schemaVersion": 39,
"tags": \[\],
"templating": {
"list": \[\]
},
"time": {
"from": "now-6h",
"to": "now"
},
"timepicker": {},
"timezone": "browser",
"title": "New dashboard",
"uid": "bdn9uavsiqi2oc",
"version": 1,
"weekStart": ""
}

dashboard.yaml
apiVersion: 1

providers:

# \<string\> an unique provider name. Required

- name: 'a unique provider name'

  # \<int\> Org id. Default to 1

  orgId: 1

  # \<string\> name of the dashboard folder.

  folder: ''

  # \<string\> folder UID. will be automatically generated if not specified

  folderUid: ''

  # \<string\> provider type. Default to 'file'

  type: file

  # \<bool\> disable dashboard deletion

  disableDeletion: false

  # \<int\> how often Grafana will scan for changed dashboards

  updateIntervalSeconds: 10

  # \<bool\> allow updating provisioned dashboards from the UI

  allowUiUpdates: false
  options:

  # \<string, required\> path to dashboard files on disk. Required when using the 'file' type

  path: /var/lib/grafana/dashboards

  # \<bool\> use folder names from filesystem to create folders in Grafana

  foldersFromFilesStructure: true

docker-compose.yaml
  grafana-service:
    image: grafana/grafana:latest
    container_name: grafana-container
    ports:
      - "23000:3000"
    volumes:
      - ./dashboard.yaml:/etc/grafana/provisioning/dashboards/dashboard.yaml
      - ./datasources.yaml:/etc/grafana/provisioning/datasources/datasource.yaml
      - ./dashboards:/var/lib/grafana/dashboards

The problem is that the datasource provisioning works fine. but when trying to provision a dashboard nothing seems to happen. noting special in the docker logs.
The main purpose of this project is to automatically create the dashboard and datasource when creating or rebuilding the docker container.

For anyone experiencing the same problem. apparently it's very important to use .json instead of .JSON.
This fixed the entire issue for me
